# How to override session time out in spring web application

Tags: spring-security, cloud-foundry

I am writing an application in Spring to be deployed to a Cloudfoundry container and want to override the default tomcat session timeout value from the Java buildpack. What are the options available to me if I want it to be a configurable value outside my code? i.e. avoid the use of `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int)`.

1. set-env JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.session.timeout=30
2. some way in application properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using Spring Boot. If so, you could set `server.session.timeout=30` in an [`application.properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) file that gets included with your app. This file is usually in `/src/main/resources` in the source tree and is bundled into the jar file at build time.

Comment: The server.session.timeout only works for Spring Boot apps leveraging an embedded server bundled in a Jar file, correct?